# how to get first and last selected uibutton title on uiscrollview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I am creating multiple  `UIButtons (example- around 40 buttons) in`UIScrollview` and i want to get a string for first and last buttons selected (FROM -TO)

Comment: why not store them while your creating them?

Comment: use tag for each buttons button.tag = //set a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any `tags` and big array to hold all titles and match to retrieve that title. But there is an easy way to that.

Just create one action method and connect all buttons to this method.

Then when the user pressed the button, action method will get called.

In that method get the title of that button and store it in a `NSMutableArray`. So you now have got the two titles after you pressed the two buttons.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
      [titleArray addObject:sender.titleLabel.text ];
}
```